# Is it possible to recreate a file from an opened file descriptor?

Tags: c, linux, unix, system, inode

Now, this question may seem weird, and it probably is, but to give some context, I've been reading [this](http://linuxgazette.net/105/pitcher.html) to learn about i-nodes in which the author gives an interesting example:

```
{
  FILE *fp;

  fp = fopen("some.hidden.file","w");
  unlink("some.hidden.file"); /* deletes the filename part */

  /* some.hidden.file no longer has a filename and is truly hidden */
  fprintf(fp,"This data won't be found\n"); /* access the data part */
  /*etc*/
  fclose(fp); /* finally release the data part */
}
```

This allows to create a "hidden" temporary file.

My question here being: is there any way to recreate a filename that points to the inode held opened by `fp` **after** the call to `unlink()`?

*Disclaimer: I do not intend to do this in real code; I'm merely (re)learning about i-nodes and wonder if this is possible.*

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to give a name to an open file descriptor.

Comment: From the [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/2/unlink): "If the name was the last link to a file but any processes still have the file open the file will remain in existence until the last file descriptor referring to it is closed. "

Comment: @BartFriederichs: Sure, that is what was explained in the link I gave. But it doesn't really answer my question, which is more: "Is there a way to recreate a file pointing to the currently opened "i-node" before it gets destroyed ?"

Comment: The opened "file" will still show under /proc/"pid"/fd/ , I'm unsure of you can create a (sym)link from that though.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid it is not possible because the `link` system call demands a valid file name (which means, an existing link) rather than an UNIX file descriptor. There is no `flink` function in [the Single UNIX Specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/unistd.h.html).

Comment: Yep, but there could be some other, low-level function that deals with i-nodes. I just don't know where to look ;)

Comment: You would be very OS-specific, I'd say, I quick Googling got me here: http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-8.html (frist hit, you might want to look a little further; I googled 'kernel inode handling').