# mkstemp() - is it safe to close descriptor and reopen it again?

Tags: c, posix

When generating a temporary file name using mkstemp(), is it safe to immediately call close() on the file descriptor returned by mkstemp(), store the file name generated by mkstemp() somewhere and use it (at a much later time) to open the file again for writing a temporary file? Or will this temporary file name become available again as soon as I call close() on it?

The reason why I'm asking is that I'm wondering why mkstemp() returns a file descriptor at all. If it is safe to close() the descriptor immediately, why does it return a descriptor at all? mkstemp() could close it then on its own and just give me a file name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  In between the time when you use `mkstemp()` to create the file and the time when you reopen it, your adversary may have removed the file you created and put a symlink in its place pointing to somewhere else altogether.  This is a TOCTOU — Time of Check, Time of Use — vulnerability which the use of `mkstemp()` largely avoids, provided you keep the file descriptor open.

Once you close the file descriptor, all bets are off in a sufficiently hostile environment.

Note that even if you keep the file descriptor open, an adversary might remove the file, or rename it, and then create their own file (symlink, directory) in its place.  The file descriptor remains valid.  You could use `stat()` to get the name information and the `fstat()` to get the file descriptor information, and if the two match (`st_dev` and `st_ino` fields), then you're probably still OK.  If they differ, someone's got at the file — if you rename it, you may be renaming their file rather than the one you created.

While the file originally created by `mkstemp()` still exists, the name will not be regenerated.  In general, successive calls to `mkstemp()` will create distinct names anyway, but the name is guaranteed to be unique at the moment of creation (see the `O_EXCL` flag for [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html)).

And just in case you're wondering, no — there isn't a way to associate a name with a file descriptor (there is no hypothetical `int flink(int fd, const char *name)` system call).  There was a question about that on one of the Stack Exchange sites a while ago, and the answer was definitely negative, with references to the Linux Kernel mailing list and so on.  One such question is [Is it possible to recreate a file from an opened file descriptor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16169149/is-it-possible-to-recreate-a-file-from-an-opened-file-descriptor/), but I think there was a more thorough version of the question too.

Comment: Ok, this is a security concern. But can it happen that a successive call to mkstemp() returns *the very same filename* in case the one from a former call to mkstemp() has been close()'d?

Comment: `mkstemp()` could only return the same name twice if the original file had been removed; if it still existed, it would not return the same name again.

Comment: Ok, thanks. That's pretty much what I wanted to know :)

Answer (score 4):

The [mkstemp](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mkstemp.html) function specifically uses descriptors instead of filenames to avoid race conditions that are commonly associated with its predecessors such as [mktemp](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mktemp.html). In fact, the "s" in "mkstemp"  means "secure", because the race condition can be a source of vulnerability (e.g. if you use the temporary file to store JIT code, for example, and someone guessing/stomping the file before you open it could cause your application to load/run the provided code rather than the code that your program generates).

Once you close the descriptor, nothing prevents another application from writing a file with the same name, so please don't do that. You should retain the descriptor for as long as the temporary file is needed (and close the descriptor once the temporary file is no longer going to be used by your program).

Comment: Thanks. Of course I know the risk that another program can change the file once it's closed but I can live with this risk. I just wanted to know whether it could happen that even mkstemp() returned the same name again but that doesn't seem to be the case then.